# Scala Actors vs Akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm learning about Actors using Scala. I found this great implementation of The Santa Claus Problem [here](https://github.com/remeniuk/scala-santa-claus/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/vasilrem/santa/actors/SantaClausSimulation.scala). However, this is using Scala Actors instead of Akka Actors. There is a particular part that I don't understand how to do with Akka Actors, starting at line 80:

```
/*(line 80)*/object Secretary extends Actor{

  def act = loop(Group[Elf](3), Group[Reindeer](9))

  private def addToGroup[T <% Helper](helper: T, group: Group[T]) = {
    val updatedGroup = group.copy(helpers = helper :: group.helpers)
    if(updatedGroup.hasSpace) updatedGroup else {
      Santa ! updatedGroup
      group.copy(helpers = List[T]())
    }
  }

  // How to implement this using 'receive' with akka
  private def loop(elves: Group[Elf], reindeers: Group[Reindeer]):Unit = {
    react {
      case Idle(reindeer: Reindeer) => loop(elves, addToGroup(reindeer, reindeers))
      case Idle(elf: Elf) => loop(addToGroup(elf, elves), reindeers)
    }
  }

}
```

I'm using this [guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html) to migrate it to Akka Actors, and I understand that the act method should be replaced with receive. But I don't understand how to do the same loop using receive. An explanation or a sample code would be helpful

Comment: Can you mark the line 80 here (target line).

Comment: @nash_ag I put a comment to be more clear

Comment: To be clear for anyone stumbling upon this question.  Akka actors are the official actors for Scala starting in Scala 2.10 and Scala actors are deprecated as of 2.11. Everyone should be using Akka actors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`context.become`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome) like this:

```
def receive = loop(Group[Elf](3), Group[Reindeer](9))

private def loop(elves: Group[Elf], reindeers: Group[Reindeer]): Receive = {
  case Idle(reindeer: Reindeer) => context become loop(elves, addToGroup(reindeer, reindeers))
  case Idle(elf: Elf) => context become loop(addToGroup(elf, elves), reindeers)
}
```

Comment: This is what I need! Thanks. Just to be clear on how it works: a message is sent and the receive methods gets it and then since both cases in `loop` use become, any new message will be sent to `loop`? @senia

Comment: @apSTRK: Actually it would be better to rename function `loop` to `createBehavior` here. It don't process messages, it creates function that will be used to process messages. Note that `Receive` is the type alias to `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, and it is subtype of `Any => Unit`.

Comment: @apSTRK: `react` method of `scala` actor don't process messages either. It registers listener for next message. So implementations are quite similar. The only difference is function that registers new listener: `react` in `scala` vs `become` in `akka`. Note also that `become` registers listener for any number of new messages, but `react` is only for single message.

Comment: It's starting to make more sense now. I need to make more research to see why Scala is using Akka Actors instead now. One more thing, in `line 66` `Futures` is used. How has that changed with akka?

Comment: @apSTRK: you should not use `await`. You could convert `Seq[Future[T]]` to `Future[Seq[T]]` using `Future.sequence`, then you should combine this future with delayed future using `firstCompletedOf` like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20794853/406435) then you should send message `Continue` to `self` in `onSuccess` of this combined future. Then you should change actors behaviour with `become(waiting, discardOld = false)` to `waiting`: `{ case Continue => {unstashAll(); unbecome()}; case _ => stash() }`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591331/406435) for `stash()`.

Comment: @apSTRK: it allows you to preserve all incoming messages without blocking thread (`await` blocks thread and actor should not do so).

Comment: @apSTRK: you can get `Future` from akka actor using ask pattern instead of `!!`

Comment: thanks!I will try all of these. Most of these concepts are new to me, but this is leading me in the right direction

Comment: do you mind explaining what this is doing? `val futureWithTimeout =
  futures.map{ f => Future firstCompletedOf Seq(f.map{Some(_)}, timeout) }` specifically this part: `f.map{Some(_)}

Comment: @apSTRK: 1. in your case it should be `val futureWithTimeout = Future firstCompletedOf Seq(Future sequence futures, timeout); futureWithTimeout onComplite {_ => self ! Continue}`

Comment: @apSTRK: In that answer: `def getFutureResultAsSomeOrNoneAfterTimeout[T](f: Future[T]): Future[Option[T]] = Future firstCompletedOf Seq(f.map{r => Some(r)}, timeout); val futuresWithTimeout =  futures map getFutureResultAsSomeOrNoneAfterTimeout`.

Comment: thanks, I was pretty close. But I'm having the same problem I had before. `Seq(Future sequence futures, timeout)` returns something of type `Seq[Object]` instead of `TraversableOnce[Future[NotInferedT]]`. I'm not sure why this is happening, is it because of how I'm building `futures`? (`val futures: Seq[Future[Any]] = helpers map { _ ask Order }`) 
Sorry for asking a lot of questions, I'm not sure if I should be creating a new question

Comment: @apSTRK: what is the type of `Future sequence futures` and what is the type of `timeout`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66865/discussion-between-apstrk-and-senia).