# Sequencing `Future`s with timeout

Tags: scala, future, scala-dispatch

I utilized the `TimeoutScheduler` introduced at [Scala Futures - built in timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304471/scala-futures-built-in-timeout).

However, now my program does not terminate as before without `TimeoutScheduler`.

I have two `Future`s: `res1` and `res2`. Both with a timeout of 15 seconds. In the end I sequence both `Future`s in order to shutdown the HTTP executor properly in the `onComplete` callback. Without using `withTimeout` the program terminates right after `http.shutdown`. But with using `withTimeout` is doesn't. Why? There must be some further futures...

```
import java.net.URI
import scala.util.{ Try, Failure, Success }
import dispatch._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.Logging

object Main extends App with Logging {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val http   = Http
  val github = host("api.github.com").secure 

  import timeout._
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.language.postfixOps
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val req: dispatch.Req =  github / "users" / "defunkt"
  val res1 = http(req > dispatch.as.Response(_.getHeaders().get("Server").asScala)) withTimeout (15 seconds) recover { case x => 
    logger.debug("Error1: " + x.toString) 
    Nil
  }
  val res2 = http(req > dispatch.as.Response(_.getHeaders().get("Vary").asScala)) withTimeout (15 seconds) recover { case x => 
    logger.debug("Error2: " + x.toString) 
    Nil
  }

  Future.sequence(res1 :: res2 :: Nil) onComplete { case _ => 
    http.shutdown()               // without using `withTimeout` the program terminated after `http.shutdow`
    TimeoutScheduler.timer.stop() // thanks to @cmbaxter
  }
}

object timeout {
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
  import scala.concurrent.Promise
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import org.jboss.netty.util.Timeout
  import org.jboss.netty.util.TimerTask
  import org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer
  import org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException

   // cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304471/scala-futures-built-in-timeout
  object TimeoutScheduler {
    val timer = new HashedWheelTimer(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    def scheduleTimeout(promise: Promise[_], after: Duration) = {
      timer.newTimeout(new TimerTask{
        def run(timeout: Timeout){              
          promise.failure(new TimeoutException("Operation timed out after " + after.toMillis + " millis"))        
        }
      }, after.toNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    }
  }
  implicit class FutureWithTimeout[T](f: Future[T]) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

    def withTimeout(after: Duration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
      val prom = Promise[T]()
      val timeout = TimeoutScheduler.scheduleTimeout(prom, after)
      val combinedFut = Future.firstCompletedOf(List(f, prom.future))
      f onComplete { case result => timeout.cancel() }
      combinedFut
    }
  } 
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome, Best, /nm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used my code exactly as described, then my guess is that the Netty `HashedWheelTimer` that sits under the `TimeoutScheduler` object is not being terminated.  You could try explicitly calling `stop` on it, after calling `http.shutdown` like so:

```
TimeoutScheduler.timer.stop
```

Now if you wanted the Netty `HashedWheelTimer` to use a daemon thread, then you can use one of the constructors on it (I'm seeing them in 3.6.6-Final) that accepts a `ThreadFactory` and then use a custom `ThreadFactory` that sets the daemon flag to true.

Comment: Well, I only slightly modified your code. Do you think this is the matter? The entire code is in my initial post. Yours is at the very end. Or maybe `HashedWheelTimer` is not daemonic (suggested by Viktor Klang)?

Comment: Yes, the `HashedWheelTimer` thread is non-daemon, so you will have to explicitly stop it if you want to use that class as your efficient timer mechanism.  There might be different options out there for a timer class though, so you could also look into that.  Me using `HashedWheelTimer` was just for completeness of example.  Don't feel that you have to use it if you don't like explicitly having to shut it down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am fine with explicitly shutting it down. Just was curious if I really have to. Thanks for the clarification. Last but not least, for didactical purposes, do you know an daemonic alternative I could play with, just to get a better understanding? Best, /nm

Comment: It looks like I may have spoken too soon.  It appears that the Netty `HashedWheelTimer` supports a constructor that accepts a `ThreadFactory` that is used to spawn the thread that represents the timer.  If you use that constructor, you should be able to pass in a custom `ThreadFactory` that sets the daemon flag on the `Thread` returned to true.

Comment: Thank you for your help and investigation! You are right! I changed to `new HashedWheelTimer(new DefaultDaemonicThreadFactory, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` whereas `DefaultDaemonicThreadFactory` is a primitive copy of `Executors#DefaultThreadFactory` but with `t.setDaemon(true)`. It works! `TimeoutScheduler.timer.stop()`, in this case, is not necessary.