# Scala and time-limited processing

Tags: scala, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I'm taking Michael Genesereth's [General Game Playing (GGP) Coursera course](https://class.coursera.org/ggp-002). In GGP a player is allowed a fixed amount of time to make a move. I'm writing my players in Scala. (The underlying GGP codebase is Java.)  Does Scala provide any support (or are there any Scala libraries) that can be used to help ensure that a computation will respond in a given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/futures-promises.html) and get the result with [`Await.result(future, duration)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Await$) or one of approaches in [Scala Futures - built in timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304471/scala-futures-built-in-timeout).

Comment: I now see that another option is to use Actors and their [`context.setReceiveTimeout` method](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html).