# Wait for some timeout value for future

Tags: scala, akka, future

Suppose I have a future:

```
val fut = future(...)
```

I want to wait some time on this future, and if timeout expires future should return some predefined value.
I know that it is possible to await on future, but i want to avoid such code:

```
try {
 val result = Await.result(fut, timeout)
} catch {
 case ex: TimeoutException => ???
}
```

Maybe there is a more functional approach?

**edit**
I have an actor which is asked to return some value.
Akka's `ask` has as an implicit parameter timeout as well as `Await.result`. 
First question is how do these timeouts correlate with each others? Second question is: I want to get result from actor. I need to ask actor at first and then to await on the returned future, should I use same timeout for both functions?

Comment: What is the actor that is performing the ask doing with the result?  Is that actor then sending something based on that result back to its sender or is is just taking some action internally based on the result of the ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304471/scala-futures-built-in-timeout).

Then if you have a future with timeout behaviour it should be possible to use recover:

```
val fut = future(...)
fut.recover { case t: TimeoutException => defaultValue }
```

Edit:

**Question 1**

From the ask pattern scaladoc:

> Sends a message asynchronously and returns a
>   [[scala.concurrent.Future]] holding the eventual reply message; this
>   means that the target actor needs to send the result to the `sender`
>   reference provided. The Future will be completed with an
>   [[akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException]] after the given timeout has
>   expired; **this is independent from any timeout applied while awaiting a
>   result for this future (i.e. in `Await.result(..., timeout)`)**.

**Question2**

I would use the same timeout for both, except you want one of the two timeouts to end before the other one (e.g. you want to handle the exception from Await instead of the Failure from the future).

That said, I hope you are aware that blocking **should be avoided wherever possible**.

Comment: >>> I would use the same timeout for both, except you want one of the two timeouts to end before the other one <<< 

What if I want two different timeout behaviours (here, I am assuming Timeout can occur while sending message to the implicit Target Actor; Please correct me if I mis-understood anything here).
1> Handle Timeout while sending the message. 
2> Handle Timeout waiting for the Future to complete. 

Another follow-up question.. 
If I want the timeout waiting for message to be sent < the timeout for the actual operation within the Future to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Akka, `ask` is usually not the most idiomatic approach to this problem. You're forcing the order of events to be explicit (I ask, then wait for the response, then proceed to do some work).

It's better to "fire and forget": send the request to the actor as a normal message, then handle the response in your `receive` method as usual. This allows you to remain fully asynchronous.

Unless you really cannot do any useful work until you've received a response from this actor, it's best to avoid `ask`.

If you really must use `ask`, the `timeout` parameter is the amount of time the Akka framework will wait for a response from this actor before completing the `Future` with `AskTimeoutException`, this timeout is **independent from any timeout applied while awaiting a result for the future (i.e. in Await.result(..., timeout)**

Comment: I use actor there because I want to synchronize access to some resource. I could use synchronized method, but for me it seems more convenient to use actor for such purpose. Also that resource has to be updated with some frequency. Akka provides such facility as scheduler(one more point for akka usage)