# Handle twitter4j User Stream 420 Exception

Tags: scala, twitter, streaming, twitter4j

The actual problem is this: I open up a User Stream to populate some cache of mine, some times, this stream gets a 420 exception (Too many login attempts in a short period of time.)

How long should I wait before trying to reestablish connection?

```
   override def onException(ex: Exception): Unit = {
      Logger.info("Exception:::" + ex.getMessage + ":::" + ex.getCause)
      if (ex.getMessage.startsWith("420")) {
        // Can't authenticate for now, thus has to fill up cache hole in next start
        // Wait some time (How long?) Thread.sleep(5000L)
        // Connect via restApi and fill up the holes in the cache
        // Continue listening
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would have to use some backoff strategy here, also I wouldn't use `sleep`, I would keep my application asynchronous.

This probably is not strictly a solution to your problem since it's almost considerable pseudo code, but it could be a start. First I borrow from Play! [the timeout future definition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAsync):

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise => SPromise}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import util.Try

def timeout[A](message: => A, duration: Long, unit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
  val p = SPromise[A]()
  Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(FiniteDuration(duration, unit)) {
    p.complete(Try(message))
  }
  p.future
}
```

This uses Akka to schedule a future execution and combined with a promise returns a future. At this point you could chain future execution using `flatMap` on the timeout future:

```
val timeoutFuture: Future[String] = 
  timeout("timeout", duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

timeoutFuture.flatMap(timeoutMessage => connectToStream())
```

At this point the connection is executed only after the timeout has expired but we still need to implement some kind of reconnection mechanism, for that we can use recover:

```
def twitterStream(duration: Long = 0, retry: Int = 0): Future[Any] = {
  val timeoutFuture: Future[String] = 
    timeout("timeout", duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

  // check how many time we tried to implement some stop trying strategy
  // check how long is the duration and if too long reset.

  timeoutFuture.flatMap(timeoutMessage => connectToStream())
    .recover {
      case connectionLost: SomeConnectionExpiredException => 
        twitterStream(duration + 20, retry + 1) // try to reconnect
      case ex: Exception if ex.getMessage.startsWith("420") =>
        twitterStream(duration + 120, retry + 1) // try to reconect with a longer timer
      case _ => 
        someDefault()
    }
}

def connectToStream(): Future[String] = {
  // connect to twitter
  // do some computation
  // return some future with some result
  Future("Tweets")
}
```

What happens here is that when an exception is catched from the future and if that exception is a 420 or some connection lost exception the recover is executed and the function is re-called restarting the connection after `duration + 20` seconds.

A couple of notes, the code is untested (I could only compile it), also the backoff time here is linear (`x + y`), you may want to have a look at some exponential [backoff strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) and lastly you will need Akka to implement the schedule once used in the timeout future (Play has already Akka available), for other possibility of using timeout on futures check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304471/scala-futures-built-in-timeout).

Not sure if all this is overkill, probably there are shorter and easier solutions.